# I think I may be running two instances of Ubuntu at the same time

Tags: login

When I log in, usually I see my background and a box with my username and asking for a password.

However, recently, I see my desktop (complete with the task bar on the side and top and battery indicator and I can shut down or restart and everything) and when I log in, everything seems to be normal but then I realized that behind the icons on the left side there is actually a 2nd set. Everything works normally, I'm just scared because this has never happened before. And I have tried shutting down and restarting.

[image]

In the screenshot you can see that behind the icons there is a 2nd, different set. They are present during my log in and I can't get rid of it. It's not really doing anything but it may be slowing my system down.

Comment: Please, upload a screenshot, so we can see what you see :')

Comment: Piggybacking on edwin, `shutter` is a good screenshot program for stuff like this. Also, since you're new, you'll need to post the pictures elsewhere on the web, then post a link to them so we can see them.

Comment: You can't be running two instances of Ubuntu on one desktop machine, though you could have two users logged on at the same time. Working correctly, that would not look like what you describe.

Comment: I actually did have a screen shot but then I realized I had to upload it so yeah I'll do that right now. Also is it possible to screenshot your login page because I couldn't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably that you have taken a screenshot of your desktop and saved it as your wallpaper! Change your wallpaper and you'll see the change!

Comment: I feel really stupid right now...Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey, that's ok! I knew it might be something of that sort ;-)